# Pasar una lista 2D a json con Python

Tags: python-3.x, json, lista, bucle-for, bucles

¡Buen dia!

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos de una archivo txt para luego pasar esos datos a un formato json.
Esto es lo que llevo:

Este es al archivo:

[image: pokemon.txt]

Este es el código que llevo: **pokemon.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import json
import itertools

from itertools import zip_longest

poke_count = []
test_data = []

with open('pokemon.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

    for indice, line in enumerate(text):
        if line.startswith('Pokemon'):
            poke_count.append(indice)


    
    for inicio, fin in zip_longest(poke_count, poke_count[1:], fillvalue=None):
         trozo = text[inicio:fin]
         test_data.append(trozo)

print(test_data)

poke_json = json.dumps(test_data, indent=4, default=str)

print(poke_json)
```

Este es el resultado que llevo:

```
[
    [
        "Pokemon: Charmander\n",
        "    Tipo: Fuego\n"
    ],
    [
        "Pokemon: Bulbasaur\n",
        "    Tipo: Planta\n",
        "    Habilidades: Ocultas\n",
        "        Poder Espesura\n",
        "        Poder Clorofila\n",
        "    Peso: 6.9 kg\n"
    ],
    [
        "Pokemon: Pikachu\n",
        "    Tipo: Electrico\n",
        "    Habilidades: Normales-Ocultas\n",
        "        Poder Est\u00e1tica\n",
        "        Poder Pararrayos\n",
        "    Peso: 6 kg"
    ]
]
```

**Pero, esto es a lo que quiero llegar**

```
pokemon = {
    "pokemones": [
        {
            "name": "Charmander",
            "type": "Fuego",
        },
        {
            "name": "Bulbasaur",
            "type": "Planta",
            "hability": "Ocultas",
            "hability_power": ["Espesura", "Clorofila"],
            "weight": "6.9 kg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pikachu",
            "type": "Eléctrico",
            "hability": "Normales-Ocultas",
            "hability_power": ["Estática", "Pararrayos"],
            "weight": "6 kg"
        }

    ]  
}
```

La lista que tengo en **test_data** contiene listas, (en este caso tengo una lista de 3 elementos=pokemones) y no he podido iterarla correctamente para extraer los datos y pasar todo a un formato json.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Esto es quizás un ejercicio de alguna asignatura? O es un programa que quieres hacer tú a nivel personal? Porque si es lo segundo, te podría sugerir unos ligeros cambios en el formato del fichero de entrada para que la lectura y conversión a diccionario sea una mera línea.

Comment: ¿Cuáles cambios serían? El tema es que tengo que procesar el archivo así tal cual como está, respetando los espacios y los signos que hay en cada sentencia. :/

Comment: El [plural de pokemon](https://www.google.com/search?q=plural+pokemon) es pokemon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es crear una lista de diccionarios. Cada diccionario contiene un pokemon.

El archivo se procesa línea por línea. Sólo hay tres casos a distinguir:

1. La línea empieza con "Pokemon".
2. La línea empieza con "Poder".
3. La línea contiene un par "atributo: valor".

En el primer caso, se inicializa un nuevo pokemon (un diccionario). Todos los atributos que se lean a continuación se agregaran a él. Este pokemon se agrega a la lista al terminarse el archivo o detectarse un nuevo pokemon.

Las líneas que empiezan con "Poder" son un caso especial. Hay que descartar la palabra "Poder", quedarse con el resto de la linea, y agregar su contenido a una lista bajo la llave "Poder" en el pokemon.

En el tercer caso, simplemente se agrega una nueva llave-valor al pokemon.

Es ineficiente el uso de `readlines`. Esta función lee todo el archivo a memoria, en una lista de lineas. En su lugar, es mejor iterar sobre el archivo, lo que retorna una línea cada vez. La lógica no cambia; en ambos casos se procesa por línea.

```
import json

# La lista de pokemones
pokemones = []
# El pokemon actual
poke = None
with open('pokemon.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for linea in f:
        # Simplifiquemos la vida eliminando los espacios de sobra
        linea = linea.strip()

        if linea.startswith("Pokemon"):
            #   Termina el antiguo pokemon, comienza otro.
            if poke:
                # Agregar el pokemon antiguo a la lista
                pokemones.append(poke)
            #   Crear un nuevo pokemon.
            _, nombre = linea.split(":")
            #   Inicializarlo con su nombre
            poke = {'name': nombre.strip()}
        elif linea.startswith("Poder"):
            #   Lineas con tratamiento especial, pues no llevan ":"
            #   Además, hay que coleccionarlos en una lista y ponerlos
            #   en una entrada con llave "Poder"
            _, nombre_poder = linea.split(" ", 1)
            if "Poder" not in poke:
                poke["Poder"] = []
            poke["Poder"].append(nombre_poder)
        else:
            #   Es una línea del tipo "atributo: descripcion"
            key, value = linea.split(":")
            poke[key] = value.strip()

if poke:
    #   Agregar el último pokemon a la lista.
    pokemones.append(poke)

print(pokemones)
poke_json = json.dumps({"pokemones": pokemones}, indent=4, default=str)
print(poke_json)
```

produce:

```
[{'name': 'Charmander', 'Tipo': 'Fuego'}, {'name': 'Bulbasaur', 'Tipo': 'Planta', 'Habilidades': 'Ocultas', 'Poder': ['Espesura', 'Clorofila'], 'Peso': '6.9 kg'}, {'name': 'Pikachu', 'Tipo': 'Electrico', 'Habilidades': 'Normales-Ocultas', 'Poder': ['Est\\u00e1tica', 'Pararrayos'], 'Peso': '6 kg'}]
{
    "pokemones": [
        {
            "name": "Charmander",
            "Tipo": "Fuego"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bulbasaur",
            "Tipo": "Planta",
            "Habilidades": "Ocultas",
            "Poder": [
                "Espesura",
                "Clorofila"
            ],
            "Peso": "6.9 kg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pikachu",
            "Tipo": "Electrico",
            "Habilidades": "Normales-Ocultas",
            "Poder": [
                "Est\\u00e1tica",
                "Pararrayos"
            ],
            "Peso": "6 kg"
        }
    ]
}
```